# Vulkan validation error pCreateInfos[0] does not have fragment shader state

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm programming a game engine with the Vulkan API.
Instead of using render passes I want to use the **VK_KHR_dynamic_rendering** extension.

I'm creating a graphics pipeline with `graphics_pipeline_create_info.renderPass = VK_NULL_HANDLE;`, and a pointer to an **VkPipelineRenderingCreateInfo** assigned to `graphics_pipeline_create_info.pNext`.

My graphics pipeline contains a vertex shader, and a fragment shader stage.

My **VkPipelineRenderingCreateInfo**:

```cpp
VkFormat color_attachment_formats = {VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SFLOAT};
VkPipelineRenderingCreateInfo rendering_create_info{VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RENDERING_CREATE_INFO};
rendering_create_info.viewMask = 0;
rendering_create_info.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
rendering_create_info.pColorAttachmentFormats = &color_attachment_formats;
rendering_create_info.depthAttachmentFormat = VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED;
rendering_create_info.stencilAttachmentFormat = VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED;
```

But at the pipeline creation I am getting the following validation error:
`[ VUID-VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo-pStages-06894 ] | MessageID = 0xdfcd6d41 | vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(): pCreateInfos[0] does not have fragment shader state, but stages (VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT|VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT) contains VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT. The Vulkan spec states: If the pipeline requires pre-rasterization shader state but not fragment shader state, elements of pStages must not have stage set to VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.268.0/linux/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo-pStages-06894)`

I don't understand this message.
At first the error is that I'm not specifying a fragment shader stage, but I'm doing it correctly (checked the values with debugger).

The second thing is the linked specification entry:
Basically it says that if my pipeline does not need a fragment shader stage, I should not provide any.
But why shouldn't my pipeline need that?

Can anyone help me?

I tried to modify the `VkPipelineRenderingCreateInfo::viewMask`, because in the description of the **VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo** is a sentence, that the **viewMask** has a influence to the fragment shader stage, but I'm not sure how.

But if I assign a value, that is not 0, to the **viewMask** it requires the **VK_KHR_multiview** extension, that I don't need.

Answer (score 0):

I investigated the problem myself:

The problem was that I set `VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo::rasterizerDiscardEnable` to `VK_TRUE`.